# pg_tileserv much slower than pg_featureserv?

Tags: postgis, pg-tileserv

I'm serving data where the geometry is very simple (a grid of squares, about 1500 of them total, no big deal) but the attribute data would be a json object, quite big (about 3000 characters).

I'm experiencing very slow tile retrieval using pg_tileserv. Tiles several tens of seconds to arrive, when they do

Trying to figure it out, I was suspecting the parametrized query in the function to lack optimization, so i've simplified my function to a function without any parameter (code below), looking up in a view. It is still as much slow.
While if I serve the same view using pg_featureserv, I'm getting the whole dataset in about 300ms

It seems to be related to the size of the data attribute: if I reduce its size, it starts working properly.

Is this some know limitation ? Maybe there is some config I did wrong ?

The code for the simplified function I'm using with pg_tileserv is fairly standard:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE
            FUNCTION public.atomicrain_cells_for_today(
                        z integer, x integer, y integer
            )
            RETURNS bytea
            AS $$
            DECLARE
                result bytea;
            BEGIN
                WITH
                bounds AS (
                  SELECT ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y) AS geom
                ),
                mvtgeom AS (
                  SELECT t.id, ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), bounds.geom) AS geom,
                    t.data
                  FROM rain_last_day t, bounds
                  WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 4326))
                )
                SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'default')
                INTO result
                FROM mvtgeom;

                RETURN result;
            END;
            $$
            LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
            STABLE
            PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Context: I'm running the services on docker, with standard images (no pgtuned DB config)

- pramsey/pg_tileserv:latest
- postgis/postgis:14-3.2
- pramsey/pg_featureserv:latest

[Edit] Here is a dump of the corresponding tables and views: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iJUbRVhedkno_iRXYC23NXpqKlLjlSMF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe dump your data table and include a public link to it. Your function doesn't look special in any way, it could be the handling of a big json blob is actually causing distress in the PostGIS MVT generator.

Comment: What's surprising me is that pg_featureserv is returning me the whole dataset (with same json attribute) way faster than pg_tileserv it returning me a single tile.